# Tengo un problema con el login en codeigniter al momento de hacer el login,

Tags: codeigniter-3

Tengo este problema tengo ya preparado pero cuando entro al login lleno los espacios y para entrar al momento de entrar en modo administrador me devuelve al mismo inicio...

*Aca adjunto mi controlador de login*

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('personal_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('admin/login/index');
    }

    public function logear(){

        $usuario = $this->input->post('usuario');
        $clave = $this->input->post('clave');


        $result = $this->personal_model->logear($usuario, $clave);

        if ($result > 0){
            // obtenemos el usuario y el id del personal 
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
            $_SESSION['id'] = $result['id'];
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = TRUE;

            redirect('admin/');
        }else{
            redirect('admin/login');
        }

    }

    public function salir(){
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('admin/');
    }


}
```

*Aca el modelo*

```
    class Personal_model extends CI_Model {

    public function logear($usuario, $clave) {
        $this->db->where('usuario', $usuario);
        $this->db->where('password', $clave);
        $query = $this->db->get('usuarios');
        return $query->row_array();

    }
}
```

*y acá la vista*

```
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="btn-group  pull-right">
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Inicio</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php echo form_open('admin/login/logear','class="form-signin"'); ?>
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Iniciar sesión</h2>
        <input type="text" name="usuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" required autofocus>
        <input type="password" name="clave" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Entrar</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que cuando haces el loguin redireccionas para el index de admin
pero el index de admin estas cargando la vista del login nuevamente, asi que tendrias que definir que vas a mostrar en el index de admin que no sea

EDITADO:

En el index puedes ver si ya esta logueado el usuario cargar la vista que quieres y si no cargar el login:

```
public function index()
{
  if($_SESSION['logged_in']){
     $this->load->view('admin/vista/administrador')
  }else{
     $this->load->view('admin/login/index');
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok pero lo que no entiendo es donde puedo definir una vista para cargar la vista despues del login gracias deje un poco la programacion estoy volviendo de tiempo por eso tengo ese problema...

Comment: En la funcion del index puedes validar si ya esta logeado o no, y cargar en dependencia de lo que quieres revisa lo que puse nuevamente en la respuesta

Comment: Aun me presenta ese error,cuando quiero validar también, no accede a la vista del administrador..